# Delphi component or toolkit for implementing Windows 7 federated search?

Tags: delphi, plugins, windows-7, vcl

Has anybody seen a Delphi VCL component with source code that makes it easier to implement a Windows 7 federated search plugin?  If not that, how about a good source code sample or article?

Comment: Where does Delphi come into this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I want a Delphi app on the local PC to be the search provider.  The following indicates that it may be possible to have a Local app be the provider instead of a web service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385851/windows-7-federated-search-how-to-make-it-send-search-requests-to-my-net-asse

Comment: If you're looking for a component to make something easier, you could start with a description of the part you find hard. However, you're asking for a component to make a task easier when you're not even sure whether the task is possible. That other question has gone unanswered for over two years. If you want a local search provider, you could just write a Web service and direct the search to localhost.

Comment: That's pretty flimsy evidence. Looks to me like you need to do it like is says here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940456.aspx

Comment: It must be exactly what the MSDN link says you must provide: A webservice.  So what have you tried so far in implementing such a web-service in Delphi?  I doubt anyone has built a toolkit yet, but if you did decide to build one, that would be great. Step 1. implement RSS feed in your app. Step 2. Write .osdx (xml) file and feed it to Windows.. Step3. There is no step 3.

Comment: There also seems to be a way to implement [`IOpenSearchSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378289(v=vs.85).aspx) interface to provide a client-side-only data source but it's not clearly documented how to register your implementation.

Comment: That's right, @Tondrej. [The other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2385851/33732) asks how to do that. (And even if you know how to register it, there's no information on how to implement it, either. The interface defines a function that's supposed to return another interface, but what's that returned interface supposed to be?) This question asks how to make it easier in Delphi.

Comment: Ironic that IOpenSearchSource is not so very open!  Good question then.